# How local MSPs of the users allow the user side to authenticate itself in its transactions?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am reading hyperledger fabric read the docs and I am confused how local MSPs of the users allow the user side to authenticate itself in its transactions.

explain the meaning of this paragraph

> Node local MSPs define the permissions for that node (who the peer admins are, for example). The local MSPs of the users allow the user side to authenticate itself in its transactions as a member of a channel (e.g. in chaincode transactions), or as the owner of a specific role into the system (an org admin, for example, in configuration transactions).

but we use x.509 certificate to authenticate the users right ?

Answer (score 0):

You bring up a very good point in terms of the overloaded use / meaning of the term MSP as well as the "file / folder" structure used to hold cryptographic material for the various entities in Fabric.

Fabric currently supports two types of MSP:  X509 and Identity Mixer.  The default is to use X509 which means that you validate that users are part of an organization by ensuring that their X509 certificates were issued by the root/intermediate CAs defined in the organization's MSP (which typically ends up stored as part of each channel's config).

So broadly speaking, an organization's MSP defines the mechanism for validating identities (based on the issuer present in the MSP definition) and defining how to determine the "role" of those identities (for example admins are explicitly defined by having their certs in the `admins` folder and in 1.4.3 and later optionally by a specific OU in the cert).

A "local" MSP holds the actual crypto material issued by an organization's MSP.  In the case of a peer, this includes the key pair (found under `keystore` and `signcerts`) used to sign endorsements as well as the information needed to determine administrator's for the peer itself.  In the case of ordering nodes, the key pair is used for signing blocks.  For clients / users, the key pair is used to sign transactions.

To your point, a client really does not need the MSP structure ... you really just need the signing / enrollment key pair and the MSPID ... but unfortunately the MSP concept is also carried over to clients even though most of the material in an MSP structure is not required for signing transactions.